# RSpec fails upon a namespaced model assigned to blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I was doing the RSpec testing with Rails and it's failing due to the namespaced model that I assigned to its associations of the model.

**CLI:**

```
Failures:

1) Blog::BlobsController GET index assigns all blog/blobs as @blobs
 Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:blog::blobs)).to eq([blog::blobs])
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `blobs' for :blog:Symbol
 # ./spec/controllers/blog/blobs_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

spec/controllers/blog/blobs_controller_spec.rb

```
RSpec.describe Blog::BlobsController, type: :controller do
  describe "GET index" do
    it "assigns all blog/blobs as @blobs" do
      blobs = Blog::Blob.create!
      get :index, {}
      expect(assigns(:blog::blobs)).to eq([blog::blobs])
    end
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
# SNIPPED FOR BREVITY...
namespace :blog do
  resources :blobs
end
```

**app/controllers/blog/blobs_controller.rb**

```
class Blog::BlobsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]


  def index
    @blobs = Blog::Blob.all
  end

  def new
    @blob = Blog::Blob.new
  end

  def edit
    @blob = Blog::Blob.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @blob = Blog::Blob.new(blob_params)

    if @blob.save
      redirect_to @blob
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @blob = Blog::Blob.find(params[:id])

    if @blob.update(blob_params)
      redirect_to @blob
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def show
    @blob = Blog::Blob.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @blob = Blog::Blob.find(params[:id])
    @blob.destroy!

    redirect_to blog_blobs_path
  end

  private
    def blob_params
      params.require(:blob).permit(:title, :body)
    end
end
```

Is there a better way to test this controller with RSpec?

**UPDATE**:

Failures:

```
1) Blog::BlobsController GET #index assigns all widgets as @widgets
 Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:blobs)).to eq([blob])
 TypeError:
   no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/server_selector.rb:56:in `[]'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/server_selector.rb:56:in `get'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/client.rb:170:in `read_preference'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/collection/view/readable.rb:318:in `default_read'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/collection/view/readable.rb:251:in `read'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/mongo-2.0.4/lib/mongo/collection/view/iterable.rb:38:in `each'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/bundler/gems/mongoid-26f67146a7b7/lib/mongoid/query_cache.rb:207:in `each'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/bundler/gems/mongoid-26f67146a7b7/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:116:in `each'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/bundler/gems/mongoid-26f67146a7b7/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:20:in `each'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/bundler/gems/mongoid-26f67146a7b7/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb:48:in `entries'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/bundler/gems/mongoid-26f67146a7b7/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb:48:in `=='
 # ./spec/controllers/blog/blobs_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Updated spec code:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Blog::BlobsController, type: :controller do
  describe "GET #index" do
    it "assigns all blobs as @blobs" do
      blob = Blog::Blob.create!
      get :index, {}
      expect(assigns(:blobs)).to eq([blob])
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can you post the controller that you're testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test says:

```
blobs = Blog::Blob.create!
```

This is confusing, because `blobs` is plural, but you're only creating one blob. So start by renaming that to `blob`. Then `expect(assigns(:blog::blobs)).to eq([blog::blobs])` should be `expect(assigns(:blobs)).to eq([blob])`.

In the index action, you set `@blobs = Blog::Blob.all`. The assigns correspond to the controller's instance variables. There's no namespacing.

Comment: it's throwing me some `TypeError:  no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`

Comment: Please show your updated code, and indicate which line the TypeError refers to.

Comment: See my edit above, I added more code for more debugging.

Comment: This looks like a problem with your MongoDB configuration.